# How can I run multiple copies of the same app using Google ARC Welder?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I've installed the [ARC Welder](http://goo.gl/gAn0Xh) extension for Chrome. I opened it and added an apk. When I navigate to my Chrome Apps page, I see an icon of the app, and when I click on it, it launches ARC Welder and starts that app. Beautiful!

When I try to open a second copy of the app, it closes my Chrome Apps tab and sets the focus to the already-running instance of that app.

On the Chrome Apps page, I've tried right-clicking the icon to look for some option, holding control and clicking it, and opening it from a different Chrome window, but each time, it either does nothing or just directs me to the already-running instance of the app.

Is it possible to use Google ARC Welder to run multiple copies of the same app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ARC Apps only allow one instance at a time.  If you click the App icon it only refocuses the window.

It would be problematic if multiple App instances could be running simultaneously; for instance, they would share the same filesystem which was not necessarily designed to be accessed simultaneously like this.

If you want a second app instance at the same time, you would need to package it separately with a second App ID.

Answer (score 2):

after loading it in ARC Welder
this can be done in 4 steps

1. click download zip instead of test.
2. After you save the zip file you'll have to extract it to a folder.
3. Then in chrome go to the extension page and select "developer mode".
4. finally click "load unpacked extension" and select the folder you just   extracted

if you want to run multiple instances of the same app
you can simply make an copy of the folder you extracted en repeat step 4

Answer (score 0):

Docker will allow you to run multiple ARC Welder containers simultaneously. Here is a [Youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gIMtb97-pc) showing how.